# How can I scale or extrude selected edges to the outside?

Tags: transforms, extrude

Consider:

[image]

Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qnn96gvkQz9cFqGJDtE6-EbUUP-I_Oul/view?usp=sharing

.blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cxfsIRXvasJL4nldaWupl2wHCU-iOY-w/view?usp=sharing

I am trying to scale/extrude selected edges to the outside, but I can't. I tried:

- <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

Nothing helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the vertices, press G twice, then C and you'll be able to move the vertices along their edges[image]

Answer (score 5):

Enable the addon called *Mesh: Edit Mesh Tools* and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Offset Edges > Extrude*:

[image]

Then tweak the parameters in the *Operator Box*:

[image]

Comment: I don't have the Offset Edges menu in the Ctrl E menu, Blender 3.4.1

Comment: This is actually an addon which is why you don't have it

Comment: what is the name of the addon?

Comment: Oh yes you're right, this is the addon called Mesh: Edit Mesh Tools

Comment: @Alex Well, it's an official built-in addon, so he has it - it's just not enabled.